# PHPでリンク先を絶対パスで指定できない

Tags: php, html, apache, xampp

Windows 10でXAMPPを使用し、PHPのサイトを作っています。

「htdocs」フォルダ直下に「test」フォルダを作り、その中に「firstPage.php」と「secondPage.php」を作りました。
今はローカル環境のXAMPPで動かしていますが、いつかはサーバーなどに上げたいと思い(セキュリティーの話は一旦置いておいてください)、リンク先のパスを絶対パスで指定しようとしました。
ところが、firstPageはちゃんと表示されたのですが、そこからsecondPageに絶対パスを用いて移動することができません。
相対パスを用いれば移動することはできます。
firstPageのソースコードは次の通りです。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>

// これは移動できない
<?php echo '<a href='.__DIR__.'/secondPage.php>secondPage</a><br />' ?>

// これは移動できる
<?php echo '<a href=secondPage.php>secondPage</a><br />' ?>

</body>

</html>
```

ブラウザでソースを表示するとリンク部分は

```
<a href=C:\xampp\htdocs\test/secondPage.php>secondPage</a><br />

<a href=secondPage.php>secondPage</a><br />
```

と表示されていますが、正直この違いがどう影響しているのかが分かりません。
なんとなく、Apacheが上手く動いてくれていない気はするのですが・・・

追記

ブラウザ上ではリンク部分は両方とも同じように青くなっているのですが、__DIR__を使った方はクリックしても無反応です。

```
<?php echo '<a href='.__DIR__.'/secondPage.php>secondPage</a><br />' ?>
```

の「/secondPage.php」を「\secondPage.php」にしても、変化はありませんでした。
また、includeやrequire_onceでは、__DIR__を使っても読み込めます。
今のところ、リンクの場合に問題となるようです。

Answer (score 1):

ファイルのパスを表す方法として「相対パス」と「絶対パス」がありますが、これと合わせて「**ローカル環境**」と、`http`または`https`などで始まる「**インターネットアドレス**(=URL)」の違いを意識する必要があります。

`__DIR__`はあくまでローカル環境でのパスを表現する変数なので、Apacheを経由したインターネットアドレスとしての絶対パスを指定するなら`$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`を指定してみてください。

```html
<a href ="<?php echo 'http://'.$_SERVER{"SERVER_NAME"}.'/secondPage.php'; ?>">secondPage</a>
```

ローカルでテストしておりホスト名が"localhost"であるなら、`$_SERVER{"SERVER_NAME"}`にもそのホスト名が入っているはずです。

参考:
[PHP: $_SERVER - Manual](http://php.net/manual/ja/reserved.variables.server.php)
[PHP($_SERVER)サーバー変数一覧と実用例](https://www.flatflag.nir87.com/server-358)

Comment: 「__DIR__」ではなく「$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']」にしたところ、リンク部分は「<a href=C:\xampp\htdocs\test/secondPage.php>secondPage</a><br />」となりました。ただし、リンク部分は依然として、青くなっているのですがクリックしても無反応です。

Comment: HTMLのハイパーリンクは例え存在しないリンク先だろうと、(見かけ上は)未訪問のリンク先として青く表示されます。

Comment: そもそも、リンク先は絶対パスで書かないものなんでしょうか？ includeやrequire_onceで呼び出すクラスファイルなんかは、絶対パスで書くと便利そうですが。

Comment: includeやrequireで参照するファイルは基本的にローカルのファイルシステムに存在するので絶対パスでも問題ありません。一方でURLの絶対パスは`http://`から指定する必要があるので、外部ドメインのサイトを参照する時くらいしか使わないと思います。

Comment: そうだったんですね。今のところ、外部リンクを作るつもりはないので、相対パスで書くようにします。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

PHPがApacheのDocument Rootを認識しているわけではありません。__DIR__は、ApacheのDocument Rootをrootとしたパスで表されたディレクトリではなく、お使いのコンピュータのrootディレクトリをrootとし絶対パスで表されたディレクトリです。